# Pandas: how to deal with nan value when convert categories to numbers

Tags: python, pandas, nan

Suppose I have dataframe like this and there is a significant number of categorical values (around 100) in favorite_food column, which includes nan value:

```
Name | favorite_food
Anna  | apple
Barbara | banana
Charlie | apple
Danie | nan
Emily | nan
............
```

My goal is to convert categorical value to numeric like this:

```
Name | favorite_food
Anna  | 1
Barbara | 2
Charlie | 1
Danie | 0
Emily | 0
............
```

So how should I modify this code `df.favorite_food =df.favorite_food.astype('category')`?
Or is there any other way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#missing-data) the default assignment to missing values is `-1` which can be achieved with `.cat.codes`

You can use `df.favorite_food =df.favorite_food.cat.codes` for the given case, which will map the `np.nan` values to `-1`.

If you want to define a specific mapping(`np.nan = 0`- as you've stated), you can do that with a dictionary

Comment: Thanks, so simple.

Comment: @Learner132 don't forget to upvote and accept if this helped:)

Comment: Sure. By the way, I have another question, can nan be accepted as NaN? Thank in advance